# CommandError: You appear not to have the 'psql' program installed or on your path. MacOS Catalina

Tags: python, django, postgresql, path

I am working on a django web app and trying to connect and verify connection to a PostgreSQL database I had created to store webscraped data I'd like the webapp to be able to query. I have correctly set up the database in Settings.py

When I enter `python manage.py dbshell` my Atom terminal returns

`CommandError: You appear not to have the 'psql' program installed or on your path.`

As per instructions elsewhere, I tried running this is iTerm2
`export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12.3/bin:$PATH"` but nothing seemed to change and I am still receiving the error.

I have PSQL 12.3 installed on my computer through postgress.app and it is functioning normally.

Comment: did you restart the command prompt after you added postgres bin folder into your path?

Comment: Yes, I did. Still nothing.

Comment: ./ manage.py dbshell psql  try running this command / does this recognize psql ?

Comment: it still isn't working, however the rest of my program seems to be functioning well and the db is definitely connected. Thanks for your help